# AChartEngine TimeSeries issue with Date on x axis

Tags: android, string, time-series, achartengine, java.util.date

i need to put Date on x axis of line graph. i've all elements stored as String inside database, and date string  is formatted as

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss
```

Before plotting diagram, i need to convertthat String Date object. I've try in this way:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
series.add(dateFormat.parse(list.get(i)[2]), Double.valueOf(list.get(i)[0]));
}
```

but when on execution time, on Y axis the value it's correct, on x i don't have date, but some string like

```
1378817460000
```

and for example, a date string like

```
2013/09/10 14:51:01
```

on x axis is represented like

```
1.378817461E12
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are creating and displaying a line chart instead of a time chart.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you pass date format into ChartFactory:

```
    graphicalView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(
            getApplicationContext(), dataset, renderer,"HH:mm:ss");
```